# SharpZipLib make tar.gz with directory name prefixed to filenames

Tags: c#, archive, sharpziplib

I'm using SharpZipLib to make a tar.gz archive, but I need to prefix a directory name to the filenames. That is, the files going into the archives look like `foo.exe`, but the archive needs to know them as `foo-1.0/foo.exe`, so the correct directory structure will be created on unpacking.

The input files are *not* already in a directory with the correct name, so the archiving process, needs to set the names.

This is what I have so far:

```
    var archiveName = $"bin/{projectVersion}.tar.gz";
    using var archiveStream = File.Create(archiveName);
    using var gzipStream = new GZipOutputStream(archiveStream);
    using var archive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gzipStream);
    archive.RootPath = projectVersion;
    foreach (var path in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(publishPath)) {
        var entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(path);
        entry.Name = $"{projectVersion}/{Path.GetFileName(path)}";
        archive.WriteEntry(entry, true);
    }
```

where `projectVersion` = e.g. `"foo-1.0"`.

I was hoping either setting `archive.RootPath`, or setting each `entry.Name` to the appropriately prefixed string, would do the job, but even though I am doing both, when I unpack the resulting archive, the files just get dumped into the current directory.

What am I missing?

Comment: Setting archive.RootPath makes so [that this prefix is removed from entries names](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Tar/TarArchive.cs/#L338). So you should not set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to modify the way you set the `entry.Name`, i.e. setting the `entry.Name` with the prefixed directory.
The key would be to make sure the full path, including the directory name, is correctly assigned to each entry in the archive.

```cs
var archiveName = $"bin/{projectVersion}.tar.gz";
using var archiveStream = File.Create(archiveName);
using var gzipStream = new GZipOutputStream(archiveStream);
using var archive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gzipStream);

foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(publishPath)) {
    var entry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath);
    // Make sure the directory structure is preserved in the entry's name
    entry.Name = $"{projectVersion}/{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}";
    archive.WriteEntry(entry, true);
}
```

That now takes each file in `publishPath`, prefixes it with the `projectVersion` directory, and sets the `entry.Name`.
That makes sure upon extraction, the directory structure `foo-1.0/` will be created, and files will be placed inside it.

Plus, `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(publishPath)` is changed to `Directory.GetFiles(publishPath)`, to make sure only files are processed, not directories. That should avoid potential issues with directory entries.